# python pandas: name-value pair to single row

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a table:

```
ID  Name  Value
1   a     100
1   b     200   
2   a     101
2   b     201
```

How can I convert it to a single row table, as below?

```
ID  a    b
1   100  200
2   101  201
```

Comment: Hint: What feature would you use if you were to go about doing this in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straightforward pivot.

```
df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Name', values='Value')

Name    a    b
ID            
1     100  200
2     101  201
```

Or equivalently by setting the index and unstacking.

```
df.set_index(['ID', 'Name']).squeeze().unstack('Name')
```